# 'Do While' loop does not generate new timestamp based values inside it

Tags: file, shell, loops, timestamp, do-while

consider this  do while loop

```
find  $filepath  -iname  "$var*" | < commands > 
while read filename; do
logfile=$var/$var1/$filename_"`date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S`".log
echo "<a long command > > $logfile" >> commandfile.ksh
done
```

so for every iteration of $file it should generate a new value
that is what I want  **a new timestamp** for every instance of file that comes in 
When I see the generated ksh file -the $logfile is set to the SAME value

Am I missing something here. I don't want to  have the logfile calculation inside the echo because there's a lot of escaping and confusion. But if for every file it should generate a time-stamp based value , those values should not be the same ..right ?
I would expect 1 iteration at least 1 s apart.
But if its like in the comments maybe this would do it

```
find  $filepath  -iname  "$var*" | < commands > 
while read filename; do
sleep 1
logfile=$var/$var1/$filename_"`date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S`".log
echo "<a long command > > $logfile" >> commandfile.ksh
done
```

Comment: What in the world is `| < commands >` supposed to be?

Comment: ...and, err, why wouldn't the timestamps be identical? This loop runs pretty quickly, after all, so if it processes two results in the same second, they'll have the same string generated by the date command.

Comment: also, using `$PATH` as an argument to `find` is almost certainly wrong, as `PATH` is an environment variable with a very specific meaning. (This is part of why it's better to use lower-case names for non-environment variables, which I note you're doing elsewhere).

Comment: ...also, you should be using the `-print0` argument to `find` and `IFS='' read -r -d '' filename` if you _really_ want to avoid corner cases around odd filenames, escaping, etc.

Comment: I am not referring to the PATH env . I will correct the  Q .Sorry for the confusion. Read  but the time it get to the loop - filename will output just the filename ( nothing else ) and there are no spaces in the filename

Comment: "read but the time it get to the loop"? I don't know what these words mean in this context.

Comment: ...anyhow -- this would be easier to solve if you gave us a standalone reproducer; right now, the code given to demonstrate the problem isn't runnable standing alone -- requires a bunch of setup (filepath, var, var1, etc; creation of files; etc).

Comment: yeah i think the sleep will fix it. T Y for your help